# Usage of “would” and “will” in the given context

Tags: subjunctives

I would like to know why is **would** used in the following paragraph. For sure, we could have used **will** or **may**. Isn’t it?

It is from an editorial section of a newspaper:

> India's ease of doing business
> Harmonization of laws, procedures and rates of taxes **will** improve environment of compliance as all returns to be filled online, input credits to be verified online reducing need to deal with different tax authorities. It **would** also discourage mere invoice shipping.

Comment: If this example was transcribed correctly: “_will improve environment of compliance_” is not standard English.  The whole first sentence has multiple problems.

Answer (score 0):

The structure of the paragraph is:

> Harmonization [...] **will** improve [... and] It **would** discourage [...]

and is not OK because it breaks [parallelism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelism_(grammar)).

To be OK it should read either:

> Harmonization [...] **will** improve [... and] It **will** also discourage [...]

or:

> Harmonization [...] **would** improve [... and] It **would** also discourage [...]

---

If parallelism is not wanted, e.g. because one action is certain (improve) while the other one is uncertain (discourage), then the text should read something like:

> Harmonization [...] **will** improve [... and] It **might** also discourage [...]

---

So your assumption that "would" is not proper was OK, as well as you were close about the use of "may".

Comment: There is no need for parallelism in two separate sentences.

Comment: There may be no need, but sometimes things just sound better, with it. At least to me.